# Error trying to load Metafont

Tags: metafont

I ran`mf` in terminal and got this error. Does anyone know how to resolve it?
Context: I installed Metafont from the standard MacTex install. Thank you!

```
dyld[759]: Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libSM.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/universal-darwin/mf
  Reason: tried: '/opt/X11/lib/libSM.6.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libSM.6.dylib' (no such file)
zsh: abort      mf
```

Comment: Quite likely you don't have installed X11. Try `mf-nowin`. Or install XQuartz from https://www.xquartz.org/

Comment: @egreg OMG it worked, thank you! I never even heard of X11 before.

Comment: X11 is a standard windowing library for Unix systems. The `mf` binary is linked to X11 libraries for showing output as nobody has ever taken the burden of linking it with macOS libraries for creating windows: too much work for just a few users. The `mf-nowin` binary is incapable of showing output.